# ARM - Unable to query connections

Tags: nyx

I'm running an exit node on my Ubuntu V-Server.

I'm also using ARM to monitor it and of course, I have a dedicated user for the Tor-Server and I think, that this is the source of the problems.

Because, when I start ARM and Tor, I get the following Log-Entries

```
 09:52:22 [ARM_NOTICE] We were unable to use any of your system's resolvers to get tor's connections. This is fine, but means that the conn-
   ections page will be empty. This is usually permissions related so if you would like to fix this then run arm with the same user as tor
   (ie, "sudo -u <tor user> arm").
 09:52:07 [ARM_NOTICE] Unable to query connections with lsof, trying ss
 09:51:52 [ARM_NOTICE] Unable to query connections with sockstat, trying lsof
 09:51:37 [ARM_NOTICE] Unable to query connections with netstat, trying sockstat
 09:51:22 [ARM_NOTICE] Unable to query connections with proc, trying netstat
```

Confusing is, I see some connections under the connection tab, but they seem to dessappear after some runtime.

And even more confusing, Tor is running from the same user as ARM since ARM starts Tor...
I'm a little bit lost here.

I'm happy for every input and idea

EDIT: I'm directly connecting to the user via SSH and start arm in a screen session. the executing user has all permissions needed and can at least run netstat.

**SOLUTION!! : all it needed was this flag in the torrc** `DisableDebuggerAttachment 0`

Comment: How do you start arm? `arm` or `sudo arm` or in another way?

Comment: i'm connecting to my tor user via ssh and start arm in a screen session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION!! : all it needed was this flag in the torrc `DisableDebuggerAttachment 0`